# Javascript Event Listner Issue

Tags: javascript, css, animation

The console in the Chrome developer tools shows no errors, the div loads, but the animation play state remains paused - what am I doing wrong?

```
document.getElementById("design").addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", animation);

function animation(){
    "use strict";
    document.getElementById("profile").classList.add("animation");
    location.href = "#profile";
}
```

CSS

```css
#design {
position: relative;
-webkit-animation: mixdesign;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
-webkit-animation-duration: 30s;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: all ease-in-out;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
z-index: 8;
}


/* Profile */

#profile {
position: relative;
-webkit-animation: profile;
-webkit-animation-duration: 30s;
-webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: all ease-in-out;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.animation { -webkit-animation-play-state: running; }
```

Comment: Is element being animated ?

Comment: Forgive me I am new to javascript what should I put?

Comment: Is css animation taking place ?

Comment: design animates without issue, I'm hoping that on animation end of design the profile div will animate. However, profile remains paused.

Comment: @Darren can you create a JSFiddle? That would make it easy for others to understand/resolution of your problem.

Comment: I will do - thank you Rasjesh

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mm0o5jhw/ I trying to make profile do the same sequence as design once the animation has completed on design. as in design fades in, fades out then on first animation end profile does the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you were assigning class once transition ends, the existing class `css` property  that takes priority over.
>
> You can make it override them using the `!important` keyword.

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/mm0o5jhw/3/)

```js
document.getElementById("design").addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", animation);

function animation() {
  "use strict";
  document.getElementById("profile").classList.add("animation");
}
```

```css
#design {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: design;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: all ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  z-index: 8;
}
/* Profile */

#profile {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: profile;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: all ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.animation {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: running!important;
}
@-webkit-keyframes design {
  10%, 90% {
    -webkit-opacity: 1;
  }
  0%,
  100% {
    -webkit-opacity: 0;
  }
}
/*  Profile: (Animation) */

@-webkit-keyframes profile {
  10%, 90% {
    -webkit-opacity: 1;
  }
  0%,
  100% {
    -webkit-opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="design">Design</div>
<div id="profile">profile</div>
```

Comment: Thats wonderful - thank you!!! One question is it possible to repeat this multiple times, over five animations - animation end trigger run on two and so on.  Do I just need to change the function name?